# Add attributes to object using array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

how can I add several attributes to a sub-sub-object in ES6 by using the keys of objects from an array ?

I have this:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 'abc-test',
  },
  {
    id: 'xyz-test',
  },
];




const t = {
  a: {
    filters: {
      tOne: [],
    }
  }

};
```

The result should look like this:

```js
const t = {
  a: {
    filters: {
      tOne: [],
      'abc-test': [],
      'xyz-test': [],
    }
  }

};
```

What I tried

```
...data.map((el) => [el.id]),
```

How to solve it ? I know that this could be done by using .forEach but I would like to use another ES6 Array.prototype functions if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I know that this could be done by using .forEach but I would like to use ES6 Array.prototype functions if possible."_? `forEach` is an "Array.prototype" function like any other.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the word "another" in my description. See updated description.

Comment: `forEach` is really the best choice here. The other functions have other usages. I mean you can use `reduce` like `data.reduce((acc, o) => (acc[o.id] = [], acc), t.a.filters)` or use `map` as a `forEach`, but that would be like using a shoe to spread butter on a piece of bread, you can do it, but why would you do that when you have a knife/`forEach`?!!

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` is an `Array` function (or as you like to call it: an `Array.prototype` function). Among all the other Array functions, `forEach` is the best fit for what you need. The other ones have other usages.

So, simply use `forEach` to loop over the objects in the array and assign the properties directly to `t.a.filters`:

```
data.forEach(o => t.a.filters[o.id] = []);
```

**Example:**

```js
const data = [ { id: 'abc-test' }, { id: 'xyz-test' } ];

const t = { a: { filters: { tOne: [] } } };

data.forEach(o => t.a.filters[o.id] = []);

console.log(t);
```

Comment: Likely doesn't get better than this!

Comment: @Nick I think your answer is valid giving that [OP clearly doesn't want to use `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906439/add-attributes-to-object-using-array/58906490#comment104075752_58906439). You may consider undeleting your answer.

Comment: Sure, I undeleted it, but I'm not a fan of doing things inefficiently, which my solution is compared to yours

Comment: @Nick Ehem, you mean like [using a shoe to spread butter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906439/add-attributes-to-object-using-array/58906490#comment104076696_58906439) lol

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of `reduce` and the spread operator.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 'abc-test',
  },
  {
    id: 'xyz-test',
  },
];

const t = {
  a: {
    filters: {
      tOne: [],
    }
  }

};

const newKeys = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.id] = [];
  return acc;
}, {});

t.a.filters = {
  ...t.a.filters,
  ...newKeys
};

console.log(t);
```